# How to add lines to a gnuplot with image?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having trouble trying to add lines to an image plot. Here's an example illustrating the problem

```
plot 'xyz.dat' using image
set arrow 0,0 to 1,1 nohead
replot
```

Yet no lines appear. Is it even possible to add lines to an image plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `arrow` in front of the image:

```
set arrow front from 0,0 to 1,1 nohead
plot 'xyz.dat' with image
```

Comment: There should probably be `set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1 nohead`